# Q-Chem QM/MM options

Tags: q-chem, qmmm

I am trying to setup QM/MM calculations with QChem using user-defined connectivity and MM parameters. But the official manual is not detailed about some options. Mostly I am interested in the procedure of accounting angles and torsions across QM/MM linkage. How it is usually calculated during QM/MM? And is there any additional keys in $rem section to control QM/MM job for QChem?
Thanks!

Comment: Great question! The main problem is about how to do QM/MM in Q-Chem when dealing with link atoms correct?

Answer (score 3):

The [Q-Chem manual edition 5.2](https://manual.q-chem.com/5.2/Ch12.S3.SS1.html) is much better at describing QM/MM

However, to answer your main question there are no angles and torsions across a link atom. The link atom is a fictitious hydrogen that is added when you break the QM and MM region at a bond. This is done to maintain the proper valency/avoid dangling bonds in the QM region. The MM region is also affected in some methods, for example in additive QM/MM schemes the fractional charge that occurs due to partitioning the system into QM and MM regions is smeared out amongst the remaining MM atoms.

Q-Chem automatically insert the link atoms depending on the definitions of the QM and MM regions.

> Link atoms for the ONIOM model and YinYang atoms for the Janus model are not
>   specified in the $qm_atoms section, as these are inserted
>   automatically whenever a bond connects a QM atom and an MM atom.

Note however, that this only works if the linked atom is a carbon.